# How can I write a program that asks multiple choice questions then performs input actions for each answer?

Tags: java, function, math, input

I am trying to write a program in which a user has to pick one answer out of a multiple choice question. If that user picks one out of three choices, then the user has to enter a number for the program to calculate it. My question that I want the program to ask is "Would you like to calculate a square root, a logarithm, or a factorial?". Also, will I be able to incorporate if-else conditions into the same program? Here is my code so far:

```
System.out.println("Would you like to calculate?");
String choice = new choice[3];
choice[0] = "Square root";
choice[1] = "Logarithm";
choice[2] = "Factorial";
choice = scan.nextString();

if (choice = "Square root") {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to square root: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(x));
} else if (choice = "Logarithm") {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to log: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(Math.log(x));
} else {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to do factorial: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(factorial(x));
}
```

I feel like my code here is incorrect. This is my first time writing a program that presents multiple choice questions. If you have any suggestions on how to correct this, please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: You're not clear on why your code is incorrect. You may want to add focus on a particular problem that you can't solve.

Comment: `choice = "Square root"` is not how you compare strings in Java

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
 System.out.println("Would you like to calculate?");
    System.out.println("1- Square root/n2- Logarithm\n3- Factorial");

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = scan.nextInt();

    if (choice == 1) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to square root: ");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Math.sqrt(x));
    } else if (choice == 2) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to log: ");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(Math.log(x));
    } else if (choice == 3) {
        System.out.println("Enter the number to do factorial: ");
        double x = scan.nextDouble();
        System.out.println(factorial(x));
    } else {
        System.out.println("Invalid choice");
    }
```

Also you have compared String in if with = sign. It is wrong. We use ".equal()" method to compare strings in java. e.g

```
if (choice.equal("Factorial");
```

**OR**
If you want to do this like your approach. Then you have some syntax errors. Line 2 should be new String() instead of new choice(). Also, why did you make array of string?? The correct code will be like this.

```
System.out.println("Would you like to calculate?");

String choice = scan.nextString();

if (choice.equal("Square root")) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to square root: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(Math.sqrt(x));
} else if (choice.equal("Logarithm")) {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to log: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(Math.log(x));
} else if (choice.equal("Factorial") {
    System.out.println("Enter the number to do factorial: ");
    double x = scan.nextDouble();
    System.out.println(factorial(x));
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. However, since I am now using ".equal()" for my if-else conditions, what should I replace "int choice = scan.nextInt();" with now?

Comment: @GGomes4 see my updated answer. Also, like it if it has helped you.